# pyplot for correlation matrix visualization using python for huge matrix(700 X 700)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have calculated correlation matrix for 900 feature and removed 200 highly correlated feature now reduced data having about 700 feature.

i have used classical method to plot correlation matrix:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

hm = plt.pycolor(cor_mat)

plt.show()
```

heat-map generated by this method is extremely dense and visualization is very poor how can i improve image for such a huge correlation matrix for my publication work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For heatmaps and correlation/statistical analysis based plots, I have had more luck with [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), than with matplotlib. Maybe it's worth to check it out.